# Is there an "ignore" function for Python 2.7?

Tags: python

total newbie here.

So is there any way to stop a functioning from being executed if certain condition is met?

Here is my source code:

```
answer = raw_input("2+2 = ")
if answer == "4":
    print "Correct"
else:
    print "Wrong answer, let's try something easier"
    answer = raw_input("1+1 = ")
if answer == "2":
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "False"
```

So basically, if I put 4 on the first question, I will get the "False" comment from the "else" function below. I want to stop that from happening if 4 is input on the first question.

Comment: You have problem with your indent. Also I believe this is less Python-related, more about control structures in general and basics of programming.

Comment: I don't know what indent is. And yes, this is basic programming, that's what I need help with.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation level is significant in Python.  Just indent the second `if` statement so it's a part of the first `else`.

```
answer = raw_input("2+2 = ")
if answer == "4":
    print "Correct"
else:
    print "Wrong answer, let's try something easier"
    answer = raw_input("1+1 = ")

    if answer == "2":
        print "Correct!"
    else:
        print "False"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place the code inside a function and return as soon any given condition is met:

```
def func():
    answer = raw_input("2+2 = ")
    if answer == "4":
        print "Correct"
        return
    else:
        print "Wrong answer, let's try something easier"
        answer = raw_input("1+1 = ")
    if answer == "2":
        print "Correct!"
    else:
        print "False"
```

**output:**

```
>>> func()
2+2 = 4
Correct
>>> func()
2+2 = 3
Wrong answer, let's try something easier
1+1 = 2
Correct!
```

Comment: Ashwini, thanks for that, but I haven't made it to the "define" statement yet, I am still trying to wrap my head around the indents, which seems extremely important. Cheers